# GraphQL types: What is the correct bucketing?

Tags: javascript, graphql

Neither the official graphql guide, nor the howtographql tutorial, specifies a consistent bucketing / hierarchy of types.

**From the [Official "Learn" GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/):**

> The most basic components of a GraphQL schema are object types
>
> ...
>
> Most types in your schema will just be normal object types, but there are two types that are special within a schema: Query, Mutation. [**my note**: Here they forgot subscription]
>
> ...
>
> Except for being "entry point" into schema, Query and Mutation types are the same as any other GraphQL object type, and their fields work exactly the same way
>
> ...
>
> That's where the scalar types come in: they represent the leaves of the query
>
> ...
>
> Enumeration types are a special kind of scalar
>
> ...
>
> Object types, scalars, and enums are the only kinds of types you can define in GraphQL. [**my note**: That is not entirely correct, as enums are special scalar types]
>
> ...
>
> An Interface is an abstract type
>
> ...
>
> Union types are very similar to interfaces
>
> ...
>
> Input types look exactly the same as regular object types, but with the keyword input instead of type

**From [HowToGraphQL](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/2-more-graphql-concepts/)**:

> In GraphQL, there are *two* different kinds of types.
>
> - Scalar types
> - Object types
>
> ...
>
> enums are special kinds of scalar types.
>
> ...
>
> An interface can be used to describe a type in an abstract way.
>
> ...
>
> Union types can be used to express that a type should be either of a collection of other types.

**My Best Guess**

- There only exists *two* types in GraphQL:

  - Object type
  - Scalar type
- Object type includes

  - Custom object types
  - 3 special object types: Query, Mutation, Subscription
- Scalar type includes

  - 5 built-in scalar types
  - Custom scalar types
  - Enumeration type
- Interface and Union

  - These are *not* actually types
  - They are mechanisms used to *describe* object types
- Input type

  - Again, not actually a type
  - It is a mechanism through which object and scalar types can be used as inputs in queries

**Question**

Is there a correct (official) bucketing? Is my "best guess" above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL has a [specification](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/) that describes the type system in detail. I would read the specification carefully, as it may answer other questions you have about GraphQL as well. You should take what other websites state with a grain of salt as it may be either outright wrong, use the incorrect terminology or oversimplify things (to not overwhelm readers that are new to GraphQL).

> The fundamental unit of any GraphQL Schema is the type. There are six kinds of named type definitions in GraphQL, and two wrapping types.
>
> The most basic type is a Scalar. A scalar represents a primitive value, like a string or an integer. Oftentimes, the possible responses for a scalar field are enumerable. GraphQL offers an Enum type in those cases, where the type specifies the space of valid responses.
>
> Scalars and Enums form the leaves in response trees; the intermediate levels are Object types, which define a set of fields, where each field is another type in the system, allowing the definition of arbitrary type hierarchies.
>
> GraphQL supports two abstract types: interfaces and unions.
>
> An Interface defines a list of fields; Object types that implement that interface are guaranteed to implement those fields. Whenever the type system claims it will return an interface, it will return a valid implementing type.
>
> A Union defines a list of possible types; similar to interfaces, whenever the type system claims a union will be returned, one of the possible types will be returned.
>
> Finally, oftentimes it is useful to provide complex structs as inputs to GraphQL field arguments or variables; the Input Object type allows the schema to define exactly what data is expected.

The two wrapper types the spec mentions -- `List` and `Non-Null` are described later. A `List` is "a special collection type which declares the type of each item in the List", while a `Non-Null` wraps an existing type and makes null an invalid response (all types are nullable by default).

The spec also describes `root operation types`. There are three root operation types -- `query`, `mutation` and `subscription`. Only `query` is required. These are not separate types in themselves, both rather parts of the schema definition that effectively point to some other type. All three must be Object types.

```
schema {
  query: Foo
}

type Foo {
  someField: String
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again. I completely agree that specifications typically represent the only safe source of information. I will hop right into it.